# Why did NIST remove The Lempel-Ziv Compression test from the Statistical Test Suite?

Tags: random-number-generator, statistical-test

NIST removed "The Lempel-Ziv Compression" test from the [Statistical Test Suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22b.pdf) in revision 2008 and above and has not incorporated it since – see revision [2010](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22rev1a.pdf).

Why was it removed? Does it no longer provide sufficient testing of a PRNG or was it simply superseded by better tests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the paper *On Lempel-Ziv Complexity of Sequences* by Doganaksoy and Gologlu,

> A test based on Lempel-Ziv complexity was used in the NIST test suite, to test the randomness of sequences. However the test had some weaknesses. First of all, the test could only be applied to data of a specified length: $10^6$ bits. Moreover, the test used empirical data generated by SHA-1 (under randomness assumptions) for estimating the expected value of Lempel-Ziv complexity of sequences of length $10^6$ bits. Apparently, the data generated by SHA-1 led to not-so-good an estimate, hence, for instance, first $10^6$ bits of the binary expansion of $e$ failed the randomness test. Using asymptotic formulae for an estimate will not work either, since the sequences, as we will see in the forthcoming sections, are distributed tightly around the mean. Recently, apparently because of the spelt out reasons, Lempel-Ziv test had been excluded from the NIST test suite.

The Crypt-XS package, part of the NIST suite, includes the simply named sequence complexity test, which is based on Lempel-Ziv compression.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the test was dropped because it's NIST implementation was poor, whilst theoretically the test is valid? Thus $e$ should pass the test if  it were properly constructed?